# Facing difficulty while adding an EditText values in a List

Tags: android

I have the 10 EditText field in my application. I want to add the values in a list once i give the submit.

I have used addTextChngedListener in my code.

```
name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                nameValue = s.toString();
                nameList.add(nameValue);
            }
        });
```

But if i give the values like this means then it is adding like j, jo, joh ,john.

```
john
michel
nishan
clorem
```

After giving submit then I want to iterate this all values.

Actually I want to see the length as 4. But It is showing the length based on changing the every letter. How can I deal this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `addTextChangedListener` is fired for *EACH LETTER*

Comment: add value in List at EditText get enter event. may it will work.

Comment: why are you using `addTextChangedListener` ?? You can handle `onClick` of Submit button and get value of EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove previously added incomplete string before adding new string.

Use following code in beforeTextChanged() function:-

```
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

              nameValue = s.toString();
              nameList.remove(nameValue);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this technique.

```
ArrayList<EditText> eList;
        someButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                eList = new ArrayList<EditText> ();
                eList.add(Edittext1);

                for (int i = 0; i <= eList.size (); i++) {
                    EditText field = eList.get (i);
                    if (field.getText ().toString ().length () == 4) {
                        // Do something...
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

P.S. you can do this on button click.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `addTextChangedListener`. You can use OnClick of button

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String value =editText.getText().toString();



       if(value.length == 4 ){
           //  Do your stuff here
       }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to accomplish this using `TextWatcher`. Please try the following method:

- Give incremental IDs to your EditTexts (like et_1, et_2,etc)
- On SUBMIT click event, add the following code:

  ```
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    EditText txt = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("et_" + i,"id",getActivity().getPackageName()))

    nameList.add(txt.getText().toString());
  }
  ```

You can then iterate through the list